# Effective bits calculation along the array in specified position on STM32

Tags: c, arrays, bit

I'm wondering if someone know effective approach to calculate bits in specified position along array?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'calculate'? Do you mean counting the amount of `1` bits in each column?

Comment: Please show desired output for your sample input and try to describe in prose how exactly you want to "calculate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that OP wants to count active bits

```
size_t countbits(uint8_t *array, int pos, size_t size)
{
    uint8_t mask = 1 << pos;
    uint32_t result = 0;

    while(size--)
    {
        result += *array++ & mask;
    }
    return result >> pos;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop the array values and test for the bits with a bitwise and operator, like so:

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
// 1 - 001
// 2 - 010
// 3 - 011
// 4 - 100
// 5 - 101

int i, bitcount = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    if (arr[i] & (1 << 2)){ //testing and counting the 3rd bit
        bitcount++;
    }
}

printf("%d", bitcount); //2
```

Note that i opted for `1 << 2` which tests for the 3rd bit from the right or the third least significant bit just to be easier to show. Now `bitCount` would now hold `2` which are the number of `3rd` bits set to `1`.

[Take a look at the result in Ideone](https://ideone.com/cfQTnR)

In your case you would need to check for the 5th bit which can be represented as:

- `1 << 4`
- `0x10000`
- `16`

And the 8th bit:

- `1 << 7`
- `0x10000000`
- `256`

So adjusting this to your bits would give you:

```
int i, bitcount8 = 0, bitcount5 = 0;

for (i = 0; i < your_array_size_here; ++i){
    if (arr[i] & 0x10000000){
        bitcount8++;
    }
    if (arr[i] & 0x10000){
        bitcount5++;
    }
}
```

If you need to count many of them, then this solution isn't great and you'd be better off creating an array of bit counts, and calculating them with another `for` loop:

```
int i, j, bitcounts[8] = {0};

for (i = 0; i < your_array_size_here; ++i){
    for (j = 0; j < 8; ++j){
        //j will be catching each bit with the increasing shift lefts
        if (arr[i] & (1 << j)){
            bitcounts[j]++;
        }
    }
}
```

And in this case you would access the bit counts by their index:

```
printf("%d", bitcounts[2]); //2
```

[Check this solution in Ideone as well](https://ideone.com/qMpCP6)

Comment: What is the relation of your `1<<2` to the two bits in each array element OP seems to be interested in? The count of "third bits", i.e. bits 2 in the sample data is 0.

Comment: @Yunnosch I mean as in 3rd bit from the right or third least significant bit. The bit i chose has in fact no relation to the bits the OP is interested in, i just chose them because it was easier to demonstrate, but i can easily change the values

Comment: Seems a good idea. While doing that also change to handle two bits per array member.

Comment: Also, your guess that OP intends "calculating" to mean "counting" seems a little optimistic.

Comment: @Yunnosch That's a valid point. I figured by the image, that OP actually wants to count the active bits, but it isn't very explicit

Answer (score 1):

Let the bit position difference (e.g. 7 - 4 in this case) be `diff`.

If 2<sup>diff</sup> > n, then code can add both bits at the same time.

```
void count(const uint8_t *Array, size_t n, int *bit7sum, int *bit4sum) {
  unsigned sum = 0;
  unsigned mask = 0x90;
  while (n > 0) {
    n--;
    sum += Array[n] & mask;
  }
  *bit7sum = sum >> 7;
  *bit4sum = (sum >> 4) & 0x07;
}
```

---

If the processor has a fast multiply and `n` is still not too large, like `n < pow(2,14)` in this case.  (Or `n < pow(2,8)` in the general case)

```
void count2(const uint8_t *Array, size_t n, int *bit7sum, int *bit4sum) {
  // assume 32 bit or wider unsigned
  unsigned sum = 0;
  unsigned mask1 = 0x90;
  unsigned m = 1 + (1u << 11);  // to move bit 7 to the bit 18 place
  unsigned mask2 = (1u << 18) | (1u << 4);
  while (n > 0) {
    n--;
    sum += ((Array[n] & mask1)*m) & mask2;
  }
  *bit7sum = sum >> 18;
  *bit4sum = ((1u << 18) - 1) & sum) >> 4);
}
```

Algorithm: code is using a mask, multiply, mask to separate the 2 bits. The lower bit remains in it low position while the upper bit is shifted to the upper bits.  Then a parallel add occurs.

The loop avoids any branching aside from the loop itself.  This can make for fast code. [YMMV](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ymmv).

With even larger `n`, break it down into multiple calls to `count2()`

Comment: The only problem is that the `n` can a very small number. In the worst scenario 1

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Unclear how a small `n` is a problem.  Did you mean a small `diff`? (as noted in "If 2**diff > n")

Comment: do not take it personally :).  It was just the remark that n can be as small as one. Stm32 may have up to 2M continuous memory